# How can I achieve tear down in OpenTest framework

Tags: scripting, yaml, android-testing, teardown, opentest

I want to turn off the bluetooth at the end of testcase even if any intermidiate step in testcase get failed, it should turn off the bluetooth (i.e. achieve it as teardown step).

How to achieve teardown in Opentest?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: I have tried "checkpoint : true" keyword.

Comment: The test execution should jump to Tear Down step after the very first failed test step. But checkpoint continues the test execution even if one of the step get failed which is unnecessarily increasing execution time.

Comment: Can you post the yaml that is not working with any variations and the results from each?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `macro` for your teardown process and run it as the last step of every test. For every step prior to this macro call, you will have to include the `checkpoint: true` keyword.